# How to change the value of a variable when an option is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, select

I am trying to change the value of a variable in javascript when each option is selected in a select. For example if option 1 was selected then the variable would be worth 10, if option 2 was selected then the variable would be worth 20 etc.

How can I do this

```
var exerciseValue = {
price: 5
}
var noExercise = document.getElementById('noExercise');
noExercise.addEventListener('click', function(){
  exerciseValue.price = -150;
})
var lightExercise = document.getElementById('lightExercise');
lightExercise.addEventListener('click', function(){
  exerciseValue.price = -50;
})
}



<select type="number" id="exerciseInput">
  <option value="noExercise" id="noExercise">Sedentary(little or no exercise)</option>
  <option value="lightExercise" id="lightExercise">Light(1-3 times/week)</option>
  <option value="moderateExercise" id="moderateExercise">Moderate(4-5 times/week)</option>
  <option value="activeExercise" id="activeExercise">Active(daily exercise/intense exercise 3-4 times/week)</option>
  <option value="veryActiveExercise" id="veryActiveExercise">Very Active(intense exercise daily)</option>
  <option value="extraActiveExercise" id="extraActiveExercise">Extra Active(very intense daily or physical activity)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Put the number as the actual value of the option instead of duplicating the id. Then add a "change" eventlistener to the <select> instead and read `Number(this.value)`

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for some value that are not implemented in the code, how is the code supposed to know?
The solution I can provide you is to set an attribute to every option with the value you want to set to the price, so when you click on the option you can use the following code:

```
exerciseValue.price = option.attr.data
```

where `option.attr.data` is something like this

```
<option value="noExercise" id="noExercise" data=50>Sedentary(little or no exercise)</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `{` in your code on line 12. You should also change your event listeners to

```
var exerciseInput = document.getElementById("exerciseInput");
exerciseInput.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    var opt = evt.target.value;
    // opt returns the "value" of the <option> elements
    console.log("you chose: " + opt);
    
    if(opt == "noExercise") {
      exerciseValue.price = 10;
    }
    // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the event listener to the select and have the value that needs to be subtracted in the value attribute of the select element.

```js
let exerciseCost = 5;

const exerciseValues = {
  "noExercise": 0,
  "lightExercise": 10,
  "moderateExercise": 20,
  "activeExercise": 30,
  "veryActiveExercise": 40,
  "extraActiveExercise": 50,
}

document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  document.querySelector("input").value = exerciseCost - exerciseValues[event.target.value];
})
```

```html
<select type="number" id="exerciseInput">
  <option value="noExercise" id="noExercise" data-value="10">Sedentary(little or no exercise)</option>
  <option value="lightExercise" id="lightExercise" data-value="20">Light(1-3 times/week)</option>
  <option value="moderateExercise" id="moderateExercise" data-value="30">Moderate(4-5 times/week)</option>
  <option value="activeExercise" id="activeExercise" data-value="40">Active(daily exercise/intense exercise 3-4 times/week)</option>
  <option value="veryActiveExercise" id="veryActiveExercise" data-value="50">Very Active(intense exercise daily)</option>
  <option value="extraActiveExercise" id="extraActiveExercise" data-value="60">Extra Active(very intense daily or physical activity)</option>
</select>
<div>
  <input type='text' value="5"/>
 <div/>
```